# Inkscape 0.48 won't update to 0.92 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, inkscape, crouton

I'm trying to update to Inkscape 0.92.
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty in crouton on an Asus c201.
I added the PPA using the following command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

once updating is finished, I check my Inkscape version and I am still in 0.48.

Any suggestions?

Update: tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` instead. Same result, see below

```
~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
 The Inkscape Stable PPA is intended to provide the current supported >release of Inkscape.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpmzuhirpt/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpmzuhirpt/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key B9A06DE3 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpmzuhirpt/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key B9A06DE3: public key "Launchpad PPA for Inkscape >Developers" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get update` only updates the package lists. Run

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after `sudo apt-get update` to actually install the available updates.

---

Alternatively, you may purge (*Warning:* removes the application and config files) Inkscape and its dependencies first and reinstall it after adding the PPA. To do that run the following commands in order.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove inkscape
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

Comment: tried this and got the same result. see edit above(sorry about the formatting)

Comment: Thanks for your help man. I've just run all three commands and I'm still having no luck. Do you know anything else it could be?

Comment: I tried that, then restarted my computer, checked again, then reran all steps. still in 0.48.4. Do you know if there is a way to check-once I add the repository- that my install actually goes there when I update? Thanks

Comment: >Inkscape 0.48.4 r9939 (Jan 22 2014)

Comment: no luck with that method. I'll keep plugging away at it and let you know if i find a solution

Comment: @KAS Could you add the output of the command: `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d | grep -i inkscape`?

Comment: > inkscape_dev-stable-trusty.list  </br> > inkscape_dev-stable-trusty.list.save

Comment: @KAS Looks alright!